# Numpy on osx 10.8.2 and python 3.2.3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, numpy

What EXACTLY do I have to do to get numpy to work? I've read that it's supported in 3.2.3 and that it should work by using setup.py. I'm getting errors talking about os_path. Is there something I'm missing?

```
Here is the full traceback:

Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Converting to Python3 via 2to3...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cameron/Downloads/numpy-master/setup.py", line 214, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/Users/cameron/Downloads/numpy-master/setup.py", line 175, in setup_package
    __file__ = os.path.join(os.curdir, os.path.basename(__file__))
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Post the full traceback.

Comment: I posted my traceback as an edit because I couldn't figure out how to post it down here. Sorry, Im new. First post. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the Python version pre-installed with Mac OS X. I strongly suggest you use a distribution where all the components (python, scipy, numpy, etc) are built to work together properly, like [macports](http://www.macports.org). Macports is a package manager for Open Source software, and it automatically resolves and installs dependencies.

After the installation of Macports, the only thing you need to do is type "sudo port install py27-numpy" or "sudo port install py33-numpy" at the command prompt, depending on whether you prefer to use Python 2 or 3 (some packages might not run on Python3 yet). This will automatically download and install the correct version of python and all other software packages that might be required for numpy to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile a Python from scratch first (by downloading the source) and not using the one shipped by Apple. See the recommendation on the [related SciPy/Numpy page](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X).